# Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol : How to deal with

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, llvm

A while ago, I developed an app with GCC compiler, now I upgrade to use Apple LLVM compiler 4.2, and getting many errors of kind : `Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol`

Here is an example:

```
@interface HomeController(PRIVATE)
NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

I know I cannot declare ivars in Categories, but if I change them to properties, it will not make sense, since some ivars are referencing extern classes.

How you usually deal with these kind of issues? Thanx in advance.

Comment: No, Instance variables may not be placed in categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be "private" what I usually do is usually create an unnamed category and declare the ivars in there like this:

```
@interface MyClass()
{
    NSArray *myArray;
}
@end
```

I'm not sure if its the named part of your category, or that you are missing the braces thats the problem, but this works for me

Comment: Note: This goes within the `.m`. file at the top.

Comment: @iWasRobbed Yes, absolutely correct, I completely neglected to mention that

Comment: Yes, it's category, I removed the private notation to shut that error, although I need them private.

Comment: @malloc It remains "private" in that they are not exposed in the header, even if you don't declare the category as "private"

Comment: Oh I see, nice info. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like that:

```
@interface HomeController (){
NSMutableArray *array;
}
```

then these variables are private...